# Convert SQL CTE expression to normal subquery

Tags: sql

is there a way to convert the following sql query with CTE expression into a subquery version?
It works on SQL 8 but i need to run this on SQL 5

```
WITH no_duplicate AS
(   SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lead_google_client_id ORDER BY lead_google_client_id DESC) AS single_googleClientID
FROM properties
)
SELECT lead_referral,
count(*) as total,
count(case when state = 'rejected' and priority != 3 then 1 end) as rejected
FROM no_duplicate
WHERE single_googleClientID=1
GROUP BY lead_referral
```

Comment: Just move the CTE query into the `FROM` clause as a subquery.

Comment: `FROM ( SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lead_google_client_id ORDER BY lead_google_client_id DESC) AS single_googleClientID
   FROM properties
) AS no_duplicate`
this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. For that you will have to provide more information, like sample data from the `properties` table.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lead_google_client_id ORDER BY lead_google_client_id DESC) AS single_googleClientID, lead_referral,
  count(*) as total,
  count(case when state = 'rejected' and priority != 3 then 1 end) as rejected
FROM properties
WHERE single_googleClientID=1
GROUP BY lead_referral
```

Comment: my goal is to retrieve a result where i need to count certain fields having the lead_google_client_id without duplicate values

Comment: Can you edit your question to add some sample input and output data? Input would be from the properties table, and the output would be the correct result you expect to get.